# How to create a two column list with random item heights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewgroup

I want to create a layout like this:

[image]

It is a `ViewGroup` with two columns. Item widths are fixed but each has random height.

How can I implement this? Should I use `GridView`, `ListView`, or ...?

Comment: You can use `StaggerredGridView` for this

Comment: `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`? some code [here](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks guys. The term was enough to find and learn.